# Retrieving computed property from controller in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to ember.js and learning it by examining the code base of a ember.js application.

It's a blogging application, in the route `/routes/posts.js` the code fetches two computed properties from controller,

```
var currentPost = this.get('controller.currentPost');
var posts = this.get('controller.sortedPosts');
```

I know ember.js infers a lot of things so I assume this `controller` refers to the controller `/controllers/posts.js`, I looked and found the definition of the property `sortedPosts`, but there is no definition of the property `currentPost`, I inserted a line of code `console.log(currentPost)` and I can see the correct value is being output in console tab in the browser dev tool but I can't figure out where this property is defined.

I was trying to find answer in ember.js official documentation but no luck.
My question is

1. does ember.js indeed infers the controller as `/controllers/posts.js` by the file name
2. is ember even smart enough to automatically load the model as `currentPost`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, ember will infer the controller as `/controllers/posts.js` if the file is there.

2) Current Post is a computed property of the controller, it is not loading the model as `currentPost`.

**NOTE**: Ember controllers are being depreciated in favor of routable components - so for new apps it is recommended to avoid controllers at all costs.

For more information on this and other future proofing issues, see: https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97

Comment: Thanks for confirming the first question. As for the second, I can't find the definition of that property `currentPost` in the controller, can this property be defined somewhere else? or is it implicitly defined by ember.js?

Comment: Will you post a link to the code you're working with? (Assuming its a git repo)

Comment: [/routes/posts.js](https://github.com/sunh3/Ghost/blob/master/core/client/app/routes/posts.js) line 39,40 retrieves the propertives. [controllers/posts.js](https://github.com/sunh3/Ghost/blob/master/core/client/app/controllers/posts.js) line 72 is the definition of sortedPosts. I can't find currentPost but it still works

Comment: A link to the whole repo.  Otherwise I'd just be guessing.

Comment: It is set in `routes/posts/post.js` line 52

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94590/discussion-between-dan-green-and-hsu).